how to add a JFrame to Java Gradle Project in Eclipse
I have a gradle project and I want to add a simple GUI to it.
When I try to instantiate a JFrame in my main method, the import javax.swing.JFrame cannot be resolved.
Am I perhaps missing any necessary plugins or dependencies in my build.gradle file?

It would help also to know what version of Java you're using.

I'm using Java 11

If you have a module-info.java file, delete it (if needed you can recreate it later via right-click on project and Configure) or in module-info.java add the required requires java.desktop; statement which is the module containing javax.swing.JFrame.

This question is similar to: Unable to Run bash script of remote Linux host using powershell in GitHub actions. If you believe it’s different, please [edit] the question, make it clear how it’s different and/or how the answers on that question are not helpful for your problem.
